# MobileFirst Platform 8.0 beta - breaks cordova-plugin-statusbar

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

After adding `cordova-plugin-mfp`, `cordova-plugin-statusbar` no longer works.

Steps to recreate:

1. Create a new Cordova project with statusbar plugin:

   ```
   cordova create test
   cd test
   cordova platform add ios
   cordova plugin add --save cordova-plugin-statusbar
   ```
2. Add the following text to config.xml:

   ```
   <feature name="StatusBar">
       <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
   </feature>
   <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
   ```
3. Run the project and note the status bar text is black (default!).
4. Change the added line in config.xml:

   ```
   <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="blacktranslucent" />
   ```
5. Run the project and note the status bar text is white (hooray!).
6. Add the cordova-plugin-mfp plugin:

   ```
   cordova plugin add --save cordova-plugin-mfp
   ```
7. Run the project and note the status bar text is black (boo!).

At this point, the StatusBarStyle changes have no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Please see the following blog post which addresses this issue: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/13/fixing-the-incompatibility-between-cordova-status-bar-plug-in-and-mobilefirst-foundation-8-0/

Confirmed.

We've opened a defect and this is currently scheduled to be resolved for the GA release of MFPF 8.0. Thanks for reporting!

There is currently no workaround available, but if there will be I'll be sure to update this answer.

Comment: Thanks Idan.  Looking forward to the fix.

Comment: @NickMaynard, see my update to the answer. Right now there is a workaround, perhaps in the future a fix...

Comment: Thanks for the workaround Idan.  When can we expect a final bug fix?

Comment: Yep, such is life... :/ on the bright side, if this question helped you it'd be great if you could mark it as resolved.