# Cordova StatusBar Plugin Method styleLightContent Not Working

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins, statusbar

My project is using MobileFirst 7.1, which has an older version of Cordova included (3.6 iirc), and I'm having trouble with the StatusBar.styleLightContent method taking effect.  I've created a deviceready function, which makes the following calls:

```
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#0d66a4");
StatusBar.styleLightContent();
```

The first two calls are successful, but the lightcontent setting isn't being applied, when I install on an IPhone with iOS 9.3.2.
Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is an incompatibility between the statusbar Cordova plugin and MobileFirst, which affects 7.1 and 8.0. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36968279/1530814

Comment: Thank you.  I saw that other post, but it, and the blog it referenced, only called out MFP 8.0.  So I didn't want to assume it also affected 7.1.